# concatenate two numpy arrays row-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to concatenate these two arrays row-wise.
thanks in advance

[image: See intended output here].

Comment: Please post your code for generating the sample dataframe, as well as what you have tried. Don't use image.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate 2 NumPy Arrays Row-wise doing this:

```
# concatenate 2 numpy arrays: row-wise
>np.concatenate((array2D_1, array2D_2))
 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

More info in [here](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/04/how-to-concatenate-arrays-in-numpy/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also saw the post but when I try this the second array will be added at the end and not in the row next to the first.